# How to set up AnyIP on Debian properly?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, ipv6

While trying to set up AnyIP on Debian, I came across way too little information on how to set it up. I came across a few blog posts and two ServerFault posts, both which just say similar things but the answers not explaining a lot.

So far I know the following:

1. Enabling AnyIP for an IPv6 subnet is done via `ip -6 route add local 2a01:beef:f0am:::/64 dev lo`
2. The IPv6 prefix must be routed to the Server.
3. There must be a local route to the Server.

Step 1 is easy enough, step 2 usually requires the Hoster to play nice and step 3 is just step 1 it seems. Are there any other steps necessary to make it work and if so: What are they and how do you do them? How would the network configuration look like?

Comment: Cleared up the question a little bit, I hope this isn't still a duplicate. The linked answer explains what, not how - the what is all over the web, the how next to nowhere.

Comment: You are still asking the same question. Yes, doing it properly requires the provider to be cooperating. But it is in their interest to cooperate because the workaround may leave their router vulnerable to DoS attacks. The answer also explains how to work around silly providers who won't cooperate. And it explains what applications need to do to support the setup.

Comment: The above link did not work for me, instead ended up asking a colleague at work about this. Kinda solved now, though I'd wish there'd be better documentation for this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I have figured out how to set it up properly. The problem was an extra : on the ip -6 route add local line. It was that simple.